# Setting DataGuardSyncLatency for Oracle Data Guard

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

With Oracle 12.2 there is a new parameter [DataGuardSyncLatency](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DGBKR/oracle-data-guard-broker-properties.htm#DGBKR-GUID-057A8CA7-DFE7-4570-9201-34FEC5634BCB) when setting up Data Guard. I keep getting the warning:

```
Warning: ORA-16714: the value of property DataGuardSyncLatency is inconsistent with the member setting
```

What value should this parameter be for protection mode: MaxPerformance with phsyical standby?

Comment: So, on the page you linked it tells you with which db parameter it syncs/checks. Make sure they both have same values DataGuardSyncLatency using dgmgrl and DATA_GUARD_SYNC_LATENCY in your spfile.

Answer (score 1):

On the primary and standby server I set:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET DATA_GUARD_SYNC_LATENCY=0 scope=both sid='*';
```

Not sure if it should be 0.